# How to attach to hex values next to each other and then display

Tags: c++, hex

Suppose I have the following.

```
int main(){
    int x = 0x02;
    int y = 0x72;
    //Figure out how to put 0x02 and 0x72 together to make 0x272.
}
```

As the comment says, I want to figure out how to put the hex values together.  It's not simple addition of numbers.

That code up there is one part of a much larger project, and I'm wondering how to solve this problem.

Comment: So you want to make a single integer value, with `x` the high byte and `y` the low byte? Read about bitwise *shift* and *or* operators.

Comment: If you wanted to put the numbers the other way round, would you want the answer to be 0x722 or 0x7202?

Comment: what is your your machine int size  ? 8,16,32,64 ?

Comment: @Ramsey Well, there's [`std::uint16_t`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer)

Comment: @MartinBonner That's not true using shift operations. These are transparent to representation and endianess.

Comment: @MartinBonner If I were to put the numbers the other way around, I would prefer 0x7202.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ:  What's not true using shift operations?  That unions are endianness specific?

Comment: Where's the union here, @Martin?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit : In an answer that I was commenting on.  I still don't understand π's comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like:

```
int main(){
  int x = 0x02;
  int y = 0x72;
  int z = x << 8 | y;
  printf("0x%x\n", z);
  z = y << 8 | x;
  printf("0x%x\n", z);
}
```

Output:

```
0x272
0x7202
```

?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is a matter of simple addition since multiplication is a lot of simple additions. :-)

I suggest using multiplication (and using **unsigned** integers):

```
unsigned int x = 0x02;
unsigned int y = 0x72;
unsigned int combined = (x * 256) + y;
// Or the equivalent
unsigned int result = (x * 0x100) + y;
```

This solution is platform independent, doesn't depend on Endinanness.